# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required)

Tags: java, mysql

I am using Tomcat version 8 and MySQL connector ver 6. Here is my context.xml:

```
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Resource auth="Container" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
             maxActive="20" 
             maxIdle="10" 
             maxWait="-1" 
             name="jdbc/MyConn" 
             username="root"
             password="mypassword" 
             type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
             url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/training_db" 
             />
```

This is the class I use for DB connection.

```
public class DBConnection {

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/MyConn");
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    System.out.println("dbConLookp():: Data Source Connection is called."+ds.getLogWriter());
    return conn;
}

}
```

This is what I have for connecting to database and do insertions.

```
try{


    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver());

    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,MIDDLENAME,PHONENUMBER,EMAILID,ADDRESS,USERPASS) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    st.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
    st.setString(2, firstName);
    st.setString(3, lastName);
    st.setString(4, middleName);
    st.setString(5, phoneNumber);
    st.setString(6, emailId);
    st.setString(7, address);
    st.setString(8, password);

    boolean rs = st.execute();
    if (!rs) {
        System.out.println("Record "+request.getParameter("id")+" is inserted successfully.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Record is insertion is failed.");
    }
    st.close();
    con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception caught:" + e);
    }
```

On Register page, when I click register, I get java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required) exception. I tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 but it didn't work. I also checked MySQL permissions and they look fine. I tried creating a different user but it didn't work as well. I tried moving creating another context.xml in my WEB-INF folder but no luck. I don't know what else can I do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone experiences the same issue, I remembered that I copied MySQL Connector JAR's into Tomcat's lib folder as suggested by a StackOverflow answer from a related question. Delete those JAR's and you'll be good to go.

I also needed to downgrade my connector version to v5.1.39. Try different connector versions if you still experiencing problems.